# vee validate no funciona

Tags: javascript, validación, vue.js

Estoy haciendo pruebas con [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) y la libreria *VeeValidate* que es para validar campos en un fomulario.

Tengo un ejemplo para validar un campo de email como el siguiente:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('email') }" >
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input v-model="email" v-validate="email" data-rules="required|email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has('email')">{{ errors.first('email') }}</p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

El problema es que cuando hago la prueba en un browser, [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) no hace la interpolación de las variables y me muestra algo como lo siguiente:

```
{{ errors.first('email') }}
```

Las versiones que estoy usando de [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) y *VeeValidate* son las siguientes:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vee-validate/2.0.0-beta.25/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
```

El codigó completo esta en el [siguiente gist](https://gist.github.com/hectorgool/40117d1c6f0e76d5cc602ee5918f5377):

¿Alguien me puede decir qué es lo que le falta al código o qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Bienvenido Sanx. Cuando publiques código **hazlo aquí** porque si por casualidades de la vida, eliminas ese gist, entonces la pregunta pierde contexto.

Answer (score 1):

[vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) no es un framework que funcione *out  of the box*, es decir, que no tengas que configurar nada. Para que Vue.js maneje el DOM del documento (virtualmente) se debe *montar* Vue en él. Y esto lo haces mediante el método `$mount`:

```
new Vue({ ... }).$mount('#app');
```

Antes de montar Vue es cuando debes de añadir los plugins:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
 data: () => ({

 }),
 methods: {

 },
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes encerrar entre comillas lo contenido en la directiva como este ejemplo:
debes de sustituir `v-validate="email"` por `v-validate="'email'"`.

Yo personarmente eliminaria `data-rules="required|email"` y solo usaria la directiva.

Te agrego el ejemplo en `jsfiddle`
[validacion basica con vee-validate](https://jsfiddle.net/jerobaal77/qfu06wbu/1/)